# How to use the number 0 as a stop/break?

Tags: python, list, input, range, user-input

The code needs to ask user to enter any numbers by choice and as many numbers as he/she wants and put them into a list. (This is not what I ask reader to focus on, just an introduction about how the code works!)

When user enters the number 0, the program needs to print the sum, average, minimum and maximum of the list, without including the zero itself.

If possible, I do not want to use any Python import libraries.

```
try:
    user_list = []

    print("PRESS 0 to see: \n\t 1. Sum \n\t 2. Average \n\t 3. Minimum \n\t 4. Maximum")

    while True:
        print("Type number by choice and hit Enter: ")
        user_list.append(int(input()))

except:
    print(user_list)
```

What I tried was to implement a `if` statement after the except statement which still gave me the oppurtinity to enter as many numbers as I wanted, but when entered a letter it stopped.

Comment: Your question seems to have stopped mid-sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly variant, if you want to use exceptions:

```py
class ProcessList(BaseException):
    pass

try:
    user_list = []

    print("PRESS 0 to see: \n\t 1. Sum \n\t 2. Average \n\t 3. Minimum \n\t 4. Maximum")

    while True:
        value = int(input("Type number by choice and hit Enter: "))
        if 0 == value:
            raise ProcessList()
        user_list.append(value)

except ProcessList:
    s = sum(user_list)
    print(f'avg = {0 if not user_list else s / len(user_list)}, sum = {s}, min = {min(user_list)}, max = {max(user_list)}')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your input and effort for making this class. I will definetly try to use it as soon as I have developed more skills in classes. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```py
user_list = []

print("PRESS 0 to see: \n\t 1. Sum \n\t 2. Average \n\t 3. Minimum \n\t 4. Maximum")

while True:
    value = int(input('Type number by choice and hit Enter: '))
    if value != 0:
        user_list.append(value)
    else: break
sum_of = sum(user_list)
max_of = max(user_list)
min_of = min(user_list)
avg_of = sum_of / len(user_list)

print(sum_of)
print(max_of)
print(min_of)
print(avg_of)
```

Comment: Ah I see what you did here, you keep appending the numbers as long as the value does not equals to 0. I missed how to implement this part in my code and this really helped me a lot. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can append all non-zero values to list, and exit from a loop if user enter a zero value:

```
while True:
    x = int(input("Type number by choice and hit Enter: "))
    if x != 0:
        user_list.append(x)
    else:
        break
```

If you use `try..except` block only to handle incorrect input, you can move it to the loop, and execution will not be interrupted when incorrect value was entered.

```
while True:
    try:
        x = int(input("Type number by choice and hit Enter: "))
        if x != 0:
            user_list.append(x)
        else:
            break
    except:
        print("Please enter a number.")
```

You can also set a prompt text as `input()` function argument.

Comment: True, the execution did not stop, even if the carachter was a letter. Which maked me think the  try except is not the ideal solution for this code.

Answer (score 1):

Give something like this a go:

```
def main():
    values = []
    while True:
        value = int(input('Enter numbers to add them to a list, enter 0 to get summary statistics'))
        if value == 0:
            break
        values.append(value)


    print('Sum: ', sum(values))
    print('Average :', sum(values)/ len(values))
    print('Min : ', min(values))
    print('Max: ', max(values))


main()
```

Here I make this into a function so that it might be re-usable.
I then create a list for the values to be added to ->
I then want to loop until the correct condition ->
I then ask for the input with some validation i.e. requiring the input to be an Integer (can change that to float if needed) ->
Then deal with the exceptions!  If 0 then break the loop (good practice to deal with exceptions first) -> append the values to the list if they have made it through the validation step.

Comment: Beaitiful code James. I am a beginnerg to functions (def) and classes, as sson as I gain more knwledge I will try out your code as well! Thank you for the effort.